# How do i show values for a horizontal stacked barplot inside the bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I have a stacked bar plot i created with this code

```
p<- ggplot(data = df21[1:20,], aes(x =Initiative, y = Frequency, fill= Topic)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Topic), width = 0.5)+ 
  geom_text(aes(label = Frequency,  #paste0(round(100*value/sum(value),2),"%")
  ),
  vjust = -1.5,
  hjust = 6,
  color = "black",
  position ="stack",  #position_dodge(preserve = "single"),
  size = 5)+
  theme_classic()+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100, by=10))+
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", width = .5)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 35))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        axis.text.x = element_text( face = "plain", size = 15, vjust= 0.5),
        axis.text.y = element_text( face = "plain", size = 15, vjust= 0.5),
        plot.title = element_text(family = "Arial", face = "bold", size = (18),colour = "steelblue4"),
        legend.title = element_text( face = "bold", size = 15, vjust= 1, hjust =-3),
        legend.text = element_text(face = "bold",
                                   colour = "steelblue4", family = "Arial", size = 8),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.8, 'cm'), #change legend key size
        legend.key.height = unit(0.8, 'cm'), #change legend key height
        legend.key.width = unit(0.8, 'cm'),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold",family = "Arial", size = 15, colour = "steelblue4") )+
  labs(title = "Topics per Initiative", y = "Counts per Topic", x = "Initiative")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=6, byrow=TRUE,
                           shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 6)),
                           ))
```

it creates this plot with the number of counts for each stack on top.
[image]

i have been playing with hjust and vjust and manage to get the numbers on top, otherwise they appear behind the plot like this.

[image]

I've been looking for solutions and playing around with the code! i need help! i really would like to have the numbers on top and in the center of each " stacked" bar. thanks!

Comment: Order matters: do your `geom_bar` and `geom_col` *before* `geom_text` and the text will be on top.

Comment: Such a simple solution! still got lots to learn! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `vjust` or `hjust` when drawing text I recommend you calculate the exact position of each label and drawing them using that as the `y aesthetic`. This will make the graph look more elegant and doesn't need manual adjustment when values change.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# create a sample data with some random
groups <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
colors <- c("a", "b", "c", "e", "f")
set.seed(100) # for reproducible examples
df <- tibble(
  Initiative = sample(groups, 20, replace = TRUE),
  Topic = sample(colors, 20, replace = TRUE),
  Frequency = round(runif(20, min = 1, max = 20), digits = 0)
)

# a sample df which will need to summarized by Initiative, Topic
df
#> # A tibble: 20 x 3
#>    Initiative Topic Frequency
#>    <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>
#>  1 2          f            19
#>  2 3          c            14
#>  3 1          a            13
#>  4 2          c            17
#>  5 4          e            16
#>  6 4          b            17
#>  7 2          f             3
#>  8 3          f            10
#>  9 2          f            12
#> 10 5          a            18
#> 11 4          f            20
#> 12 3          e             2
#> 13 3          c            12
#> 14 2          a            15
#> 15 1          a             6
#> 16 2          a             7
#> 17 3          c            15
#> 18 4          a            18
#> 19 4          a             5
#> 20 4          e             8
```

```r
# Change the fill color to Factor for easiser control orders of the variables
# this is useful for arrange the text position as well as order of fill
# variables when drawing plot.
df$Topic <- factor(df$Topic, levels = colors)

# summarized the df
summary_df <- df %>%
  group_by(Initiative, Topic) %>%
  summarize(Frequency = sum(Frequency), .groups = "drop") %>%
  group_by(Initiative) %>%
  # arrange the variables is needed as it related to how variables will
  # be displayed on graphs which decide where position of label would be.
  arrange(Initiative, Topic) %>%
  # here I calculate the label position using cumsum
  mutate(label_pos = cumsum(Frequency) - (Frequency / 2))

summary_df
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#> # Groups:   Initiative [5]
#>    Initiative Topic Frequency label_pos
#>    <chr>      <fct>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 1          a            19       9.5
#>  2 2          a            22      11  
#>  3 2          c            17      30.5
#>  4 2          f            34      56  
#>  5 3          c            41      20.5
#>  6 3          e             2      42  
#>  7 3          f            10      48  
#>  8 4          a            23      11.5
#>  9 4          b            17      31.5
#> 10 4          e            24      52  
#> 11 4          f            20      74  
#> 12 5          a            18       9
```

```r
ggplot(data = summary_df, aes(x = Initiative)) +
  # I only use geom_bar here - in OP you use both geom_bar & geom_col
  # that just created duplicated layer and doesn't need to be there.
  geom_bar(aes(y = Frequency, fill = Topic), 
           # I use position_stack with reverse = TRUE here to control
           # the order of the plot matched with my label_pos calculated
           position = position_stack(reverse = T),
           stat="identity", width = .5)+
  # drawing the text label using label_pos which will be
  # consistent and auto adjust to midpoint when your values changes
  geom_text(aes(y = label_pos, label = Frequency),
            color = "black", size = 5) +
  coord_flip() + theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>